# Postgres keyword DEFAULT is not recognised as column value in EF core?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am getting a very strange error when I insert a record into my postgres database using EF core. The library I'm using is Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.

Here is my data model, the Category has an auto-generated PK "CategoryId":

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("CategoryId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using sql query to insert a new Category record, here is the code:

```
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PortalContext>();

    string sql = @"INSERT INTO schema.""Category""(""CategoryId"", ""Name"", ""Description"") 
                        VALUES (DEFAULT, @NAME, @DESCRIPTION);";
    var nameParameter = new NpgsqlParameter("@NAME", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    nameParameter.Value = name;
     var descriptionParameter = new NpgsqlParameter("@DESCRIPTION", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    descriptionParameter.Value = description;
    var category = await context.Categories
      .FromSql(
        sql,
        nameParameter,
        descriptionParameter)
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Getting an exception from the execution, but the record is inserted into the database successfully.

> Exception - The required column 'CategoryId' was not present in the
>   results of a 'FromSql' operation.

Does anyone have encountered the same issue? And how to fix it?

Comment: Not an answer (or kinda partial), but if you omit that column entirely then PostgreSQL will use default value if it is set for that column.

Comment: If you want to pass default value in column then plz do not use that column. from below query you can understand. INSERT INTO schema.""Category""( ""Name"", ""Description"") 
                        VALUES ( @NAME, @DESCRIPTION);

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the reply. CategoryId was part of the issue.

Comment: The main problem is I'm using FromSql for an INSERT statement. I changed to ExecuteSqlCommand and removed CategoryId, now it is working